# How can I bind many ComboBox's ItemsSoure Connected to each other

Tags: wpf, binding, descriptor

I have three ComboBox. Threre are bound same ItemsSource.

This ItemsSouce type is `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<CustomKey, CustomClass>>`

**CustomKey**

```
public struct CustomKey<T1,T2> // T1, T2 is string
{
    public readonly T1 Symbol;
    public readonly T2 Column;
    public CustomKey(T1 key1, T2 key2) { Symbol = key1; Column = key2; }
}
```

**CustomClass**

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string Value{get;set}
}
```

**First.** FirstComboBox's ItemsSoure is **Dictionary.Keys**

**Second.** I want to set Second ComboBox's Items Source is FirstComboBox's SelectedItems.
 like this **Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T1**

**Third.** ThirdComboBox's ItemsSource **Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T2**

**Last.** 

This is my code...
// Source.GetNames is ItemsSource.Keys.ToList();

```
 protected virtual FrameworkElement CreateAutoCompleteComboBoxControl(PropertyItem property)
    {
        var c = new AutoCompleteComboBox();
        ContinuityBindablePropertyItem cbp = (property as ContinuityBindablePropertyItem); // cbp is First ComboBox SelectedItem Descriptor. but i don't know how to use...

        if (property.DisplayName == "Sheet") // First ComboBox
        {
            c.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Source.GetSheetNames");
        }
        else if (property.DisplayName == "TestName") // Second ComboBox
        {
            c.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Source.GetSheetNames");
        }
        else if (property.DisplayName == "Symbol") // Third ComboBox
        {
            c.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Source.GetSheetNames");
        }

        c.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, property.CreateBinding());
        return c;
    }
```

Pleas help me.
I do not speak English well. I hope you understand.

thank you.

**EDIT**
change method.

```
 protected virtual FrameworkElement CreateAutoCompleteComboBoxControl(PropertyItem property)
    {
        StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
        var c1 = new AutoCompleteComboBox { Name = "c1", DisplayMemberPath = "Key", IsEditable = property.IsEditable, ItemsSource = property.ItemsSource, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
        var c2 = new AutoCompleteComboBox { IsEditable = property.IsEditable, ItemsSource = property.ItemsSource, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
        var c3 = new AutoCompleteComboBox { IsEditable = property.IsEditable, ItemsSource = property.ItemsSource, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };

        c1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Source") { Source = MappingService.Instance, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
        c2.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Values") {  Source = c1.SelectedItem, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
        c3.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("SelectedItem.Values") { ElementName = c1.Name, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });

        c1.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, property.CreateBinding());
        c2.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, property.CreateBinding());
        c3.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, property.CreateBinding());

        s.Children.Add(c1);
        s.Children.Add(c2);
        s.Children.Add(c3);
        return s;
    }
```

i try binding path 'Values', 'Value', 'SelectedItem.Value', 'SelectedItem.Values, Change Source to C1.SelectedItem or element name = c1...

but it's not work

**Edit**
Adding image.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any xaml, or are you doing everything in code?

Comment: @joe yes i don't ues xaml. only code behind

Comment: what is the itemSource of your first combobox. Can you add the complete structure? this is not very clear Second. I want to set Second ComboBox's Items Source is FirstComboBox's SelectedItems.
like this Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T1

Third. ThirdComboBox's ItemsSource Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T2

Comment: @Nitin Add image for help my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by exactly what you are trying to do, I think I'd need a little more code, or an example to get my head around it. But I'll try address some points. Also, I'm used to xaml, so you might have to fill in the gaps of the binding code:

> First. FirstComboBox's ItemsSoure is Dictionary.Keys

Just to check, this is working?

> Second. I want to set Second ComboBox's Items Source is
>   FirstComboBox's SelectedItems. like this
>   Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T1
>
> Third. ThirdComboBox's ItemsSource
>   Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T2

These two are essentially the same problem, you want to bind to Dictionary.Keys, but have one combobox display T1 and the other T2? Okay, rather than trying to bind the ComboBox to Dictionary[FirstComboBox.SelectedItem].Keys T1 directly, I'd suggest using one of two methods.

**1. Use a multi binding converter.** Your first checkbox's ItemsSource will be bound to a list of strings. It's it's SelectedItem will be a string that is the key to the Dictionary>.

You can pass both the key and dictionary to a multibinding converter and have it return the Dictionary's keys as a list or array like this:

```
public class MyDictionaryValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //first item is our key
        string key = values[0] as string;

        //second item is our dictionary
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<CustomKey, CustomClass>> dictionary = values[1] as Dictionary<string, Dictionary<CustomKey, CustomClass>>;

        //pass our value to be bound to
        return dictionary[key].Keys.ToList();
    }
}
```

Do you know how to set converter bindings in code? Might need to research multibindings, I've only ever done it in xaml.

**2. You can also do this using intermediate properties** You don't have to bind to everything directly, you could create a property in your data object like this:

```
    public class DataContextThatContainsYourDictionary : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //notifying property that is bound to ItemsSource in the first Combobox
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<CustomKey, CustomClass>> MyDictionary { get... }

    //This is the string that's bound to SelectedItem in the first ComboBox
    public string SelectedKey
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedKey;
        }
        set
        {
            //standard notify like all your other bound properties
            if (selectedKey != value)
            {
                selectedKey = value;
                //when this changes, our selection has changed, so update the second list's ItemsSource
                SelectedKeys = MyDictionary[SelectedKey].Keys.ToList();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedKey");
            }
        }
    }

    //an "intermediatary" Property that's bound to the second Combobox, changes with the first's selection
    public List<CustomKey> SelectedKeys { get ... }
```

These both have the same result, you will ultimately bind your ComboBoxes to a List. You can then set the DisplayMemberPath to T1 for the first checkbox or T2 for the second.

Comment: adding image for  help my questions

Comment: Yes, first comboBox is working. but, second and third combobox is not working.

Comment: Have you tried using a multibinding or intermediate property?

Comment: Not yet.  time is 7:00  pm in our country. Have dinner.  I will try now.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting bindings like below: You might need to set DisplayMemberPath for your other two comboboxes too depending on which property you want to show in those.

```
 var c1 = new AutoCompleteComboBox { Name = "c1", DisplayMemberPath = "Key", IsEditable = property.IsEditable, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
 var c2 = new AutoCompleteComboBox { IsEditable = property.IsEditable, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
 var c3 = new AutoCompleteComboBox { IsEditable = property.IsEditable, VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };

 c1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Source") { Source = MappingService.Instance, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
 c2.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.Value.Keys"), ElementName = c1.Name, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
 c3.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.Value.Values"), ElementName = c1.Name, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```